# Session remembering extension for Chrome

Tags: chrome

I often need to close Chrome (and later start it again). For example to make it use less memory (this technique works, probably because of leaks), or because I'm restarting the PC to install updates, etc. I want the stuff that was open when I closed the browser to be restored when I start the browser again.

I've been using the following technique:

- Open Chrome's task manager, note PID of "Browser" process
- Kill that process with `kill -9 <pid>` in Linux and with the task manager in Windows
- When I start Chrome again, it prompts me to restore the last session.

That's a little cumbersome though. So I'm looking for an extension that simplifies it.

Requirements:

- Easy way (e.g. one click) to simultaneously save the open windows with their tabs and close them all.
- When I start Chrome again (if the last time it was closed via the extension) I want to be offered (in an obvious way, e.g. with a dialog) to restore the last session in e.g. one click. It's also acceptable if it just restores the last session without asking when I start Chrome again.
- Then, whether or not I accepted the offer to restore the session, the remembered session should be automatically deleted from the extension's data (I don't want them piling up in there).

I don't need:

- Keeping more than one saved session

**Note:** So far I've tried Session Buddy which doesn't fit the criteria.

**Edit:** I found [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/878835) which works very well without the need for an extension. I've flagged my question for closing.

Comment: Why not leave this quewstion open and post an answer, referring to the other question?

Comment: @Mawg Yes, that is a better idea.

Comment: Errrm, ***I*** could have copied that & posted it as answer, but I thought that the OP would like to.  NVM. It got done & i guess you need the points ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the settings, there is an option that says "Continue where you left off" under "On Startup" option. That should keep your tabs intact when you close and launch chrome every time.
>
> This will work for both the hotkey and manual close.

[**Source.**](https://superuser.com/a/878858/648246)

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, I don’t trust Chrome, as sometimes it loses the list of open tabs (I am not sure of the circumstances, but perhaps two crashes sin a row, before you get the chance to restore?).

So. I use the [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-manager/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi?hl=en)  extension. This has never failed me, in the years that I have been using it. It also has the advantage of allowing me to define multiple sessions, so that I can open “Newspapers”, or “music”, etc I highly recommend it

Obligatory pic follows:

[image]

And, yes, it ***does*** restore (multiple) crashed sessions, even though the pic does not show that.